# remote wget command with & symbol doesn't behave as expected

Tags: linux, bash, shell, wget

Here are some test results:

I run command on my localhost, and try to execute some command on the remote host `11.160.48.88`

### Command 1:

`ssh 11.160.48.88 "wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mirror/wget/master/README -O wgetReadme"`

expect:

File can be downloaded and be renamed to wgetReadme

result:

work as expected

### Command 2:

`ssh 11.160.48.88 "wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mirror/wget/master/README -O wgetReadme&"`

I simply add the `&` at the end of command, because I want this command to run in background

result:

**the file `wgetReadme` is null on the remote server, I don't know why**

### Command 3:

To test if the `Command 2` can be run on the remote server, I try to run the command directly on the server `11.160.48.88`

`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mirror/wget/master/README -O wgetReadme&"`

result:
There are some wget transport message print to stdout, and the file is downloaded to wgetReadme. Work corretly.

### Command 4:

I want to figure out if it is the `SIGHUP` signal kill the subprocess, and I found two evidences to prove it is not.

1. I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84737/in-which-cases-is-sighup-not-sent-to-a-job-when-you-log-out), and I try to run this on remote server `11.160.48.88`

```
$shopt|grep hup
huponexit       off
```

So the subprocess will not receive `SIGHUP` when ssh exits

2. I try to run another command to prove it

`ssh 11.160.48.88 "wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mirror/wget/master/README -O - 2>&1 > wgetReadme&"`

result:
The file can be downloaded to the target file correctly.

My question is why `Command 2` cannot work as expected?

Answer (score 3):

Because backgrounded jobs in ssh can cause the shell to hang on logout due to a race condition that occurs when two or more threads can access shared data and they try to change it at the same time and you can also solve the problem by redirecting all three I/O streams such as **> /dev/null 2>&1 &** So **Nohup** command is useful in your case and it is a **POSIX command** to ignore the HUP (hangup) signal. The HUP signal is, by convention, the way a terminal warns dependent processes of logout. So I change your code as following way:

```
ssh -f 11.160.48.88 "sh -c 'nohup wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mirror/wget/master/README -O - > wgetReadme  2>&1 &'"
```

You can read more at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it seems don't work for me. The `wgetReadme` is NULL after I run this command on my local server

Comment: Your welcome Dear Nslam. I removed the /dev/null can you try now ?

Answer (score 0):

& is a bash special characters which make process running in background.  Then , ssh will not capture anymore output of command when you run this remotely.

You should escape it with \ to be able to run your command

in your example :
`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mirror/wget/master/README -O wgetReadme\&"`

regards

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works for me. Can I ask what will ssh do if I didn't add '\' to escape it (why Command 4 works correctly)?

Comment: Good if it helps. It will run command anyway remotely, but you will not be able to see output as wget process will be detached from your ssh command.